# Is it a good practice to use intents for communication inside the same application?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm working on application where I have several modules and logic running on several threads. Sometimes I need some communication between the different threads to achieve some functionality. I started using Intents for this purpose but I'm not sure if this is a good practice in Android in general or it's an overkill (in terms of usage, performance, etc) since the intent mechanism is designed to be used for inter-app communication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between threads?  Why?  That's a bit heavyweight.  Why not just pass the threads a message with a map of the parameters?  Intents are optimized for cross process communication, they really shouldn't be used unless you're starting a new Context.  Look into MessageQueues, Handlers, and HandlerThreads for better solutions to the problem.